# How to handle a large number of replaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle a large number of jquery/javascript replaces. This is what my code currently looks like and I will be adding more words/phrases to it. I am wondering if I should be doing some sort of loop with the words in an array or an object? Or should the words maybe even be kept in a different file?

```
input = input.replace(/\band\b/g, "&")
        //COMMON ABREVIATIONS
        .replace(/\bwith\b/g, "w/")
        .replace(/\bwithout\b/g, "w/o")
        .replace(/\bpeople\b/g, "ppl")
        .replace(/\bbecause\b/g, "b/c")
        .replace(/\bestablished\b/g, "est.")
        .replace(/\bstreet\b/gi, "St.")
        .replace(/\bavenue\b/gi, "Ave.")
        .replace(/\bparkway\b/gi, "Pkwy.")
        .replace(/\blane\b/gi, "Ln.")
        .replace(/\bboulevard\b/gi, "Blvd.")
        .replace(/\bassociates\b/gi, "Assoc.")
        .replace(/\bretweet\b/gi, "RT")
        .replace(/\bapartment\b/gi, "Apt.")
        .replace(/\bdirect message\b/gi, "DM")
        .replace(/\bphoto credit\b/, "PC")
        .replace(/\bphoto cred\b/, "PC");
```

Comment: You could loop through objects/arrays with jQuery's [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), then maybe store the definitions in a different file or getting it from a DB via ajax or something.

Comment: I got a solution for that but gotta find my schoolar worksheet, give me a minute.

Comment: In your sample data what do you want should be the output?.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something, but unfortunately it doesn't catch phrases with two words. It's something wrong with the RegEx, I bet.

```js
var input = {
  'band': "&",
  'with': "w/",
  'without': "w/o",
  'people': "ppl",
  'because': "b/c",
  'established': "est.",
  'street': "St.",
  'avenue': "Ave.",
  'parkway': "Pkwy.",
  'lane': "Ln.",
  'boulevard': "Blvd.",
  'associates': "Assoc.",
  'retweet': "RT",
  'apartment': "Apt.",
  'direct message': "DM",
  'photo credit': "PC",
  'photo cred': "PC"
};

console.log('band with'.replace(/\w+/gi, match => input[match]));
```